# In an Ejb project java classes form src/main/java can't see classes from src/test/java

Tags: maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.2

Am getting an error that says

> Description Resource   Path    Location    Type
>   The import com.esprit.puzzled.test cannot be resolved   TutorialImpl.java   /Puzzled/src/main/java/com/esprit/puzzled/services/tutorial line 14 Java Problem

Note that the error wasn't there before I had to format my laptop and completely set up my work environnement again.

I've tried clean project, Update maven project, refresh project, switch workspaces but no dice.

Also Jrebel was working fine before but activating it now gives me an error at jrebel.xml file too.

screen capture

[image: screen capture]

Comment: I would say this is the expected behaviour, production code (src/main) must not see test code (src/test). Why should your production code see your test code?

Comment: You're right. It's been a while since I've worked on this project and I forgot what was what. The import was probably a misstype. Thanks for the quick answer Roland Weisleder. All what's left is how to close this thread.